# like and not like in one mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql-like

I want to do a query containing 'like' and 'not like'.

Current example: i want everything starting with '1|%' but not with '1|6|199|%' or '1|6|200|%'.

Current query:

```
'SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `category` LIKE '1|%' NOT LIKE '1|6|199|%','1|6|200|%' ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 9'.
```

But that doesn't work. Any tips? thx

Comment: "Does not work" should be a little more precise. I assume you get a syntax error - in which case Michael Haren has your solution.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Just add "and category"...

```
SELECT * FROM links 
WHERE category LIKE '1|%' 
  AND category NOT LIKE '1|6|199|%','1|6|200|%' 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 9
```

Actually, the comma separated condition is not a syntax I'm familiar with. If that's not working, try this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM links 
WHERE category LIKE '1|%' 
  AND category NOT LIKE '1|6|199|%'
  AND category NOT LIKE '1|6|200|%' 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 9
```

Comment: thx! it worked!

However, what is wrong with the following?

SELECT * FROM `links` WHERE `category` LIKE '1|6|%' AND `category` NOT LIKE '1|6|137|%','1|6|151|%','1|6|118|%','1|6|176|%','1|6|67|%','1|6|199|%','1|6|160|%' ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 9

? it shows empty but its not
thx!

Comment: if you intebd to perform several exclusion, I suggest you use SUBSTR(category, 1, 8) NOT IN ( 1|6|137|','1|6|151|', ... ).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `regexps`:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    links 
WHERE   category LIKE '1|%' 
        AND category NOT REGEXP '^1\\|6\\|(199|200)\\|'
ORDER BY
        score DESC
LIMIT 9
```

Note that `REGEXP`'s don't use indexes, while `LIKE` does.

In this query, `LIKE '1|%'` will serve as a coarse filter using the index on `category` if any, while `REGEXP`'s will fine filter the results.

Answer (score 2):

I think a bigger problem is that you have de-normalized tables. The correct answer would be to normalize your tables.

But if you can't do that, you should use commas as separators and `FIND_IN_SET()` instead:

```
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('1', category) > 1
  AND FIND_IN_SET('6', category) > 1
  AND FIND_IN_SET('199', category) = 0
  AND FIND_IN_SET('200', category) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use two inner join, probably not the best solution for this query, but could still be useful.

> SELECT * FROM links
>
> INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM links WHERE category NOT LIKE '1|6|199|%') AS escl1 ON (links.category=escl1.category)
>
> INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM links WHERE category NOT LIKE '1|6|200|%') AS escl2 ON (links.category=escl2.category)
>
> WHERE category LIKE '1|%'
>
> ORDER BY `score` DESC LIMIT 9